# Total lifetime between records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table that stores the status time for a project, and to get a lifetime of each project i just have to run a SUM of the date differences and im set, the issue comes when i include other dates from other table called "Interruptions", the interruptions table is as follows:

```
|_ID_| |_PROJ_| |_COMMENTS_| |_START_| |_END_|
----
 5  --  1080  -- testing 1 --  9/12/2017 -- 9/20/2017
 6  --  1080  -- testing 2 --  9/12/2017 -- 9/20/2017
 7  --  1080  -- testing 3 --  9/20/2017 -- 9/20/2017
```

I need to be taking the interruptions time from the total lifetime but in this case you see 2 interruptions (5 and 6) that are from 9/12/2017 to 9/20/2017, totaling (with no weekends) 6 days each, so a normal SUM of these records is 6 days + 6 days + 1 day, total 13 days, but realistically it should be a total of 7 days of interruptions only since #5 and 6 happened on the same period, it should be the same case even if for example #5 was from 9/12/17 to 9/19/17 (5 days) and #6 was from 9/11/17 to 9/20/17 (7 days), this should be 7 days (without weekends), if i had an interruption #7 say from 9/22/17 to 9/22/2017 (1 day) i should have a total of 7 days + 1 day = 8 days

hope i'm wording this right,

what would be the most efficient way to tackle this?

thanks in advance

EDITED

Project time table (Very similar)

```
|_ID_| |_PROJ_| |_STATUS_| |_START_| |_END_|
----
 1  --  1080  -- 19 --  9/8/2017 -- 9/12/2017
 2  --  1080  -- 20 --  9/12/2017 -- 9/20/2017
 2  --  1080  -- 26 --  9/20/2017 -- 9/20/2017
```

Note: These status time are consecutive and do not overlap, its the project flow, you only jump to a new status after completing the current one

Comment: Why would #7 also not overlap since it's on 9/20?

Comment: it could overlap, but there are cases where there are time gaps between interruptions, this was just an example i had at hand

Comment: Also, which version of SQL Server?

Comment: Right, but why would it be 7 days? 5, 6 and 7 all happened on the same days.

Comment: And can you provide an example of your non-interruptions table data? This can all likely be done in one query.

Comment: on this example we had #5 from 9/12 to 9/20 (6 days), #6 also from 9/12 to 9/20 (6 days) and #7 from 9/20 to 9/20 (1 day) instead of 13 days total we should present only 7 days, because that is the real time this project spent on pure interruptions

Comment: Version of SQL is 2005 (old stuff)

Comment: I guess my question is why 5 and 6 are considered the same time, but 7 isn't included in that time. It does overlap the other two.

Comment: yeap, my mistake, they do overlap, total of 6 days between the 3 interruptions

Answer (score 0):

your problem is not completely clear to me, specially the main part i.e. "`to get a lifetime of each project` "

Please re-explain your problem  if my output is wrong.
Still my script will help you find the solution.

I think Main problem is to find "`Total distinct interruption Time`" of each project

For this you can have one permanent Date Calendar table.In my example it is temp table.

> Sample data

```
declare @Interruption table(_ID_ int,_PROJ_ int,_COMMENTS_ varchar(50),_START_ date,_END_ date)
insert into @Interruption VALUES
  (5  ,  1080  ,'testing 1','9/12/2017','9/20/2017')
 ,(6  ,  1080  ,'testing 2','9/12/2017','9/20/2017')
 ,(7  ,  1080  ,'testing 3','9/20/2017','9/20/2017')

 declare @project table(_ID_ int,_PROJ_ int,_STATUS_ int,_START_ date,_END_ date)
insert into @project values
 (1  ,1080 ,19,'9/8/2017',  '9/12/2017')
 ,(2  ,1080 ,20,'9/12/2017','9/20/2017')
 ,(2  ,1080 ,26,'9/20/2017','9/20/2017')
```

> How to find "Total distinct day interruption time" excluding weekend

Main trick happen here. so you have to Test this only and let me know.

```
create table #exmDate(datecol date primary key)
insert into #exmDate
select dateadd(day,c.rn,'01/01/2017')
from(
select row_number()over(order by number)rn from master..spt_values)c

select e.*,c._PROJ_ from #exmDate e
CROSS apply(select _PROJ_, min(_START_)_START_,max(_END_) _END_ from @Interruption group by _PROJ_)c
where datecol>=c._START_
and datecol<=c._END_
and  DATENAME(dw, datecol) not in('Friday','Saturday','Sunday')



drop table #exmDate
```

If the output are correct then you can comment above "Select" proceed as below,

```
create table #exmDate(datecol date)
insert into #exmDate
select dateadd(day,c.rn,'01/01/2017')
from(
select row_number()over(order by number)rn from master..spt_values)c

--select e.*,c._PROJ_ from #exmDate e
--CROSS apply(select _PROJ_, min(_START_)_START_,max(_END_) _END_ from @t group by _PROJ_)c
--where datecol>=c._START_
--and datecol<=c._END_
--and  DATENAME(dw, datecol) not in('Friday','Saturday','Sunday')

;with CTE as
(
select e.datecol,c._PROJ_ from #exmDate e
CROSS apply(select _PROJ_, min(_START_)_START_,max(_END_) _END_ from @Interruption group by _PROJ_)c
where datecol>=c._START_
and datecol<=c._END_
and  DATENAME(dw, datecol) not in('Friday','Saturday','Sunday')
)
,cte1 AS(
select _PROJ_ ,sum(DATEDIFF(day,_START_,_END_)) TotalProjectTime
from @project p
 group by p._PROJ_
)
select _PROJ_ ,TotalProjectTime -c.TotalInterruptiontime
from cte1 p
cross apply(select count(*)TotalInterruptiontime from CTE where _PROJ_=p._PROJ_ group by _proj_)c


drop table #exmDate
```